# Different claims for id and access token

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I know how to configure custom claims https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/configure-tokens?pivots=b2c-custom-policy

The problem is the same claims are included in access token and id token.

I want to include "displayName" claim in the id token, but not in the access token, but I don't see a way to differentiate the two

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its currently not possible to have different claim set in Access Token vs ID Token.

Comment: Are there any plans to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

•   You can edit the claims in the ID token and the access token in the implicit flow only while the same is not possible for authorization code flow with PKCE since the tokens in auth code flow with PKCE are set on the client side due to which they need to be flushed out first. Also, you can configure the relying party claims to be issued in the ID token and the access token in the custom policies for that application registered in B2C.

•   Also, the relying party claims that are configured in the input claims and output claims section in the technical profile of the custom policy form the relying party definition which determines the ID token and the access token respectively. And both the tokens return with the same set of claims. You can configure the claims to be issued in the JWT token in the RP section for the implicit flow as below: -

```
   ‘ <RelyingParty>
  <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn" />
  <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
   <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
   <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
   <OutputClaims>
     <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub"/>
  <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
   </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
   </TechnicalProfile>
   </RelyingParty>

 {
    ...
    "sub": "6fbbd70d-262b-4b50-804c-257ae1706ef2",
     ...
   } ‘
```

Thus, through the token technical profile that you define for each ID and the access token in implicit flow, the claims can be passed and used accordingly.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior?pivots=b2c-custom-policy#configure-your-custom-policy

Comment: "input claims and output claims section in the technical profile of the custom policy" Which TP is this? Are you saying that the input claims in this TP = id token and the output claims = access token?

Comment: so how exactly do I configure different claims for id and access token? is it possible at all?

Comment: No, the input claims and output claims I am referring to are basically claims transformation parameters, i.e., if you are passing an attribute as a string in input claim then what its output claim in the token would be like for example, an integer, a date, etc.